# PhoneGap - install on Windows Phone but where is the app?

Tags: cordova, windows-10-mobile

I have been building a PhoneGap application and installing it quite happily onto various Android devices. Now I want to install it onto a Windows Phone (10 Mobile).

I have taken the .appx file from Build.PhoneGap and transferred it to the phone. I tap it, it asks me if I want to install it, but nothing seems to happen. The dialog is dismissed, I return to the view of the Downloads folder where the .appx file is, but I cannot find the app anywhere.

Has it crashed? Are apps hidden somewhere on Windows Phones (I've never used one before today)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to enable Sideloading of Apps, that don't come from store.

Go to `Settings App->Update & Security->For Developers` enable the option 
`Sideload Apps`.

[image]

Now copy the APPX Files of your apps to the device double click/Tab on the appx files and install the app.

Or you can [activate Device Portal/Development Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/device-portal-mobile) on the same page in the settings app

[image]

and deploy it from the browser on your developer system by opening the address that you see on your phone device portal settings page:

[image]

and clicking on "Choose File" (select here your Appx) and if you have dependencies, select them via "Add dependency" and now click on "Go" to deploy the app.

Comment: I already have developer mode enabled.
After I click Install, the dialog vanishes and nothing seems to be installed.
How do I get to App Manager on the Windows Mobile 10 phone?

Comment: as I said, activate device portal and here you see an URL. open this url in the browser on your developer system. Here you can see the entry

Comment: Sorry I did not understand fully until now. I turned on developer mode and connected via the IP to the phone, installed the app and saw it crashed due to the wrong architecture being built for.